# Why is casting from int to void * allowed?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Why is casting from `void*` to `int` and vice versa allowed in C?
Where is this used other than `pthread`?

Comment: It's just because it's handy in pthread_create. & `void*` & `int` have usually same size - 4 bytes. But you should not assume this. Ideally, you should pass integer pointer to it, instead of value. But for numeric constants, we use this hack to pass the value themselves.

Comment: See also [When is an integer<->pointer cast actually correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146813).

Comment: @anishane: `"void* & int have usually same size - 4 bytes"` - that's a very dangerous assumption - it used to be true in the good old 32 bit days, but these days most desktop and server operating systems are 64 bit (LP64 = 4 byte int and 8 byte pointer).

Comment: One reason that casting from `int` to pointer is allowed in C is so that code can access [memory mapped I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O#Example).

Answer (score 5):

***It is allowed, but the behavior is implementation-defined.***

Sometimes, under certain situation (on particular platform/ architecture), this provision *may* be useful for *quick-and-dirty* hacks/tricks involving memory addresses by using operators that needs `int` operands. [Ex: `XOR` operation]. Can be useful for memory optimization for limited-memory embedded devices.

To quote the standard regarding the functionality,

> *The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.*

Related Reading: From `c11`, chapter 6.3.2.3,

Paragraph 5:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap  representation.

and paragraph 6:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

Answer (score 2):

The following Standard references define those conversion. As you can see they are implementation defined. You should only convert if you know what you are doing and know your platform.

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>      result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>      entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
> 6. Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>      result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>      the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>      type